# RESOLVE Maven Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor and Build Failure

Tags: maven, netbeans

### Maven Error

I tried doing the tutorials for the correct installation of Maven, but whenever I try to run the command "**mvn archetype: generate**" gives me always this error. Have you tried running in **cmd** and **netbeans** and error is the same. I have searched but I only appear problems or proxy or directories.

> cd C:\Users\PC3002\Documents\NetBeansProjects; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09"
>       C:\Users\PC3002\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\maven\bin\mvn.bat -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=br.eti.teste -DartifactId=TestMaven -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackage=br.eti.teste -Dbasedir=C:\Users\PC3002\Documents\NetBeansProjects -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode archetype:generate 
>       Scanning for projects...
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
>       Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
>       Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1 Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom `Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
>       Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
>        Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
>       Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
>        Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
>       Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
>        Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
>       Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
>       Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
>       Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
>       Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused

Comment: Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused...

Comment: But how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to proxy settings, try and edit the proxy configurations at:

settings.xml file on your system (if you're running maven on the command line)
settings.xml on your ide (if you're running maven through it)

Comment: Ty i can run my ide (netbeans).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819163/maven-failed-to-retrieve-plugin-descriptor-error

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in `Windows`

and it worked since my proxy configuration in `settings.xml` file was changed

So locate and edit the file inside the `\conf` folder, for example : `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.5\conf`

```
<proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     | -->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>jorgesys</username>
      <password>supercalifragilisticoespialidoso</password>
      <host>proxyjorgesys</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>       
  </proxies>
```

- In my case i had to chage from port `80` to `8080`
- If you can´t edit this file that is located inside `/program files` you can make a copy, edit the file and replace the file located into `/program files` folder.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't have a proxy connection setup. I'm accessing the internet through a normal connection. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

     <proxies>
       <proxy>
          <active>true</active>
          <protocol>http</protocol>
          <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
          <port>8080</port>
          <username>proxyuser</username>
          <password>somepassword</password>
          <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
      </proxies>

    </settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get this error if you have not define the version id in your plugins.

Answer (score -1):

read and understand the error on which it is pointing...
it is saying that no archetype was found on path  [local (C:\Users\User.m2\repository)

so here is the solution go to Users/user/.m2/repository   folder you will see there are many folders already available one of them is "org" so now go in "org\apache\maven" here you will see that archetype folder is available so copy it from here and paste under .m2/repository/  folder where our system is looking for this folder ....