# maven archetype:generate first time execution throws error

Tags: maven-3

I'm running eclipse kepler 4.3 and maven 3.0.5 while running **maven:archetype generate** for first time it says Failed to download the required plugins.Build failed and throwing **NoPluginFoundForPrefixException**.I'm new to maven please someone assist me.

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 o
r one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3
.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact des
criptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one
of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descripto
r for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plu
gin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-b
eta-5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact d
escriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 o
r one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadat
a.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xm
l from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://re
po.maven.apache.org refused
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/
to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.mave
n.apache.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from h
ttp://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolutio
n will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or up
dates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.p
lugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
 Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://r
epo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will
not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates a
re forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-m
etadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to
 http://repo.maven.apache.org refused.
```

This is what i'm getting from command line.. and i'm using windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819163/maven-failed-to-retrieve-plugin-descriptor-error

Comment: thank you it helped a lot.Maven is pointing to wrong settings.xml and changing it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like connection has not established to remote maven repository. IE Proxy may lead to this failure.

Follow the following steps to resolve this issue:-

Step 1: Check your proxy details on - `Tools-->Internet Options-->Connections-->LAN Settings`

Step 2: copy your proxy host and port

Step 3: go to default local repository location : `Default: ~/.m2/repository` and edit the `'settings.xml'` file

search for proxy tag and fill the details like below-

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username><user-name></username>
  <password><password></password>     
  <host><proxy-host></host>
  <port>80</port>          
</proxy>
```

Default Proxy port : 80 (apply according to your settings)

if you did not found the `'settings.xml'` file on `'~/.m2/repository'` default repository location then copy this file from `'~\apache-maven-3.0.5\conf'` location.

Step 4: save the file.

Step 5: run on the command prompt-- `mvn:archetype generate`

your problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had the same problem, configure the proxy  in setting.xml file of marven folder by the command

```
sudo gksu gedit /usr/share/maven/conf/settngs.xml
```

then un-comment the proxy section and and set your proxy like below

```
<proxies>
<!-- proxy
 | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
 |
-->
<proxy>
    <id>optional</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username></username>
    <password></password>
    <host>10.3.100.207</host>
    <port>8080</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```