# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, plugins

I am getting this error message and a further one here: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4:

Even though when i go the .m2 repository with this path C:\Users\A591024.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.4

the maven-resources-plugin-2.4.jar file is there AND maven-resources-plugin-2.4.pom is also there. i have tried to delete the .m2 repository with no luck. so far maven will not build my project that i desperately need it to.

any ideas?

Comment: Take a look into your full log file i assume you will find messages like `[WARNING] ..could not be found` or similar and i assume you have other message which say not allowed to access `http://repo.maven.org/maven2` which might be caused by proxy issues etc.

Comment: also - show your pom

Answer (score 2):

it seems proxy issue please aad following in your setting.xml by grabbing LAN setting and proxy information.

```
<proxies>
      <proxy>
        <id>proxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>HOSTNAME</host>
        <port>PORT</port>
      </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

This is a frequent issue, please see the below link as well.

[Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522679/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5-or-one-of-its-dependencie)

[Maven: Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819163/maven-failed-to-retrieve-plugin-descriptor-error)

[Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523039/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-install-plugin2-4-or-one-of-its-dependenc)

Answer (score 0):

Errors might be something like

- Could not resolve `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1`
- error : `(groupId):(artifactID):(version)`

In dependencies section `pom.xml`, put

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>(groupId)</groupId>    
    <artifactId>(artifactID) </artifactId>  
    <version>(version)</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type> // here type will be whatever the groupId is 
</dependency>
```

Result will be then this dependency for above error

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>    
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>2.4</version>
    <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

Reload build and this should download the dependencies for those unresolved errors.