# I'm getting this error while clean build maven project

Tags: java, maven

Getting this error while clean build maven project.

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert:

Added all required maven dependencies.
Downloaded jar and uploaded it to .m2 repository.

need to download maven-clean-plugin:2.5.
```

Comment: can you add the pom.xml file please,  the maven log output will be helpful as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522679/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5-or-one-of-its-dependencie)

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
   <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>  
 </dependencies>

Comment: so you should be declaring the plugins in the <build> section of your pom.

Comment: a simple example will be like this: 
 <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

Comment: Based on the "Fatal Alert"-part it looks like you're hitting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824789/why-am-i-getting-received-fatal-alert-protocol-version-or-peer-not-authentic