# Java with maven wouldn't build: Cannot run program "cmd" "Malformed argument has embedded quote"

Tags: java, windows, maven, netbeans-11

I've a fresh install of netbean 11.1. 
Now I'm trying to build a project but I get the following error output:

> Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\projects\open"): Malformed
>   argument has embedded quote: "C:\Program
>   Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd"

```
cd C:\projects\open; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.5" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-11.1\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-11.1\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install\"" Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\projects\open"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd" -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install
```

I've build this project with netbeans 11.1 before but have a new pc.
and a fresh install, tho I'm sure there was no problem last time I tried to install everything.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Although this problem can be fixed by installing jdk1.8.0_221, but actually you don't need to downgrade your JDK. Just try these:

1. First exit netbeans IDE if it's open, then open netbeans configuration file from here: netbeans-Install-Dir/etc/netbeans.conf
   (Note: for me netbeans-Install-Dir is C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\etc)
2. Add the below arguments

```
-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

3. to the beginning of the string that you find at this line:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m ......."
```

Sample screenshot as shown below:
[image]
4. Save the change and start your netbeans IDE.

Comment: Still relevant with jdk.1.8.0_241.

Answer (score 62):

I have checked the release notes for JDK 13.0.1 at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/13-0-1-relnotes-5592797.html#JDK-8221858

This behavior is a regression from a security fix for JDK-8221858 (not public). Follow the link for a full description. The fix is part of JDK 8u231, JDk 11.0.5, 13.0.1 etc.

To resolve this problem, append `-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true` to `netbeans_default_options` in `<netbeans-dir>\etc\netbeans.conf`.

Comment: The Netbeans developers have picked up on this and other recent problem reports and the latest development version (which will be 11.2) has this fix applied, see https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/bf415874d97739bd23eef134a246a8a7241c011372b36cc8650bf901@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 11):

I had this error with `adopt8-hotspot (AdoptOpenJDK-1.8.0_232-b09)` and `sbt-0.13.X` for an old project.

Problem solved after setting the environment variable in windows via

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

Answer (score 8):

Did you by any chance install the latest critical update for java? jdk 1.7_241? I installed that today and was having the exact same problem. I downgraded my jdk version and it solved it completely.

EDIT: Apologies, I noticed you're using netbeans 11.1 so you probably have a later java version, in any case, you could try downgrading your java version to a previous release if you happened to update it today as the other version might have the same problem.

Comment: Downgrading the JDK is not an ideal solution. A better option involving editing the netbeans.conf file is below.

Answer (score 6):

At the time that I'm writing, I had only JDK13 installed only on my machine. After unzipped my netbeans I've got the same problem with the internal maven of my netbeans 11.1.

Apparently netbeans 11.1 does not work properly with the JDK13. I just installed the JDK 8 and the problem now is solved, without any additional configuration or parameter change.

Nontheless, since I need the JDK13, I have both installed but my netbeans.conf file is pointing to JDK8. Later, you can define the new Java platform in netbeans project configuration.

I hope this might help.

Cheers!

Comment: same goes for jdk-11.0.5

Answer (score 4):

just add -J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true to netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf

Comment: This adds nothing to the accepted answer which was posted months before yours. Please review existing answers before posting your own to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to happen with all recently released jdk version (11.0.5 and 13.0.1 at least), even with the latest Netbeans 11.2vc1 (and witnessed on NB 11.1 too).
Downgrade your jdk to 11.0.4 or 13.0.0. It fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem also occurs in version jdk-8u231. Fixing installing jdk-8u221 version

Answer (score 0):

Apache NetBeans 11.1 does indeed not support JDK 13, that's what the upcoming Apache NetBeans 11.2 is for -- latest beta: bit.ly/apache-netbeans-11-2-beta-3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with oracle jdk 13.0.1 and netbeans 11.1, but it worked for me with openjdk 13.0.1 (https://jdk.java.net/13/).