# Netbeans 9/10/11 cannot run program "cmd"

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ide

I unzipped NetBeans 11 to `C:\netbeans`, installed several versions of the JDK to `C:\java` and created a test class within NetBeans containing a main method and one line of code `System.out.print("hello world");`. When I click the *Run Project* button, the output window shows the command:

```
cd C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\NetBeansProjects\asdf; 
JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_231 cmd /c "\"\"C:\\netbeans-9\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" 
  -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.asdf.Test\" 
  -Dexec.executable=C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_231\\bin\\java.exe  
  -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\netbeans-9\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar  
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec\""
```

followed by the error:

> Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\NetBeansProjects\asdf"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\netbeans-9\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd" -Dexec.args="-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.asdf.Test" -Dexec.executable=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\netbeans-9\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec

Whether the class creates a GUI or not, it gives the same error. I've tried NetBeans 9, 10, and 11 with JDK 7, 8, and 11. Am I missing something during setup, or do I have something in a wrong directory somewhere? I'm lost.

Comment: Seems like the command line gets fudged with `"` characters that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Regarding _"I installed NetBeans 11 and created a small test class"_ you need to provide more information than that, because the reader has no idea what you actually did. State the precise actions you took in sufficient detail so that others can attempt to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Done, thanks. New to stack overflow.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No need to downgrade the JDK, just **add** this in your **`netbeans.conf`**

1. Find your *`netbeans.conf`* file. e.g.: `netbeansIstallDir/etc/netbeans.conf`
2. Find the key `netbeans_default_options` and at the start of the string add the following: `-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true`

   It should look like this:

   ```
   netbeans_default_options="-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true..."
   ```

Comment: What is this doing exactly? Am I making Netbeans less secure/stable by allowing ambiguous commands?

Comment: Might be a no-brainer, but just wanted to add, restart netbeans after doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue by installing jdk1.8.0_221 as suggested here:

[Java with maven wouldn't build: Cannot run program "cmd" "Malformed argument has embedded quote"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411279/java-with-maven-wouldnt-build-cannot-run-program-cmd-malformed-argument-has#comment103168681_58412254)

Hope this will help you too

Comment: Could you please share where you got the 221 update from? I can only find 231.

Comment: I got it from here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jdk8-downloads.html

Comment: Thanks so much. This solved my problem. Guessing update 231 changes how quotes are escaped or something.

Answer (score 1):

No need to downgrade to an older JDK version, check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484737 for a solution and the background of the change.

Comment: Then this should be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Find the key netbeans_default_options and at the start of the string add the following: -J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true

It should look like this:

netbeans_default_options="-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true..."

this if form Omer Erden, congrats...