# Cannot Create Maven Web Project in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8.2

I installed netbeans 8.2 recently and I keep trying to create a `maven web project` but I'm getting this error.

```
Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects"): 
Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\opt\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin\mvn.cmd" 
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7 
-DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
-DgroupId=com.dilini -DartifactId=mavenproject1 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.dilini.mavenproject1 
-Dbasedir=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects -Darchetype.interactive=false 
-Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" 
--batch-mode archetype:generate
```

I updated java ee plugings in netbeans, I added `settings.xml` to `C:\Users\Administrator\.m2` location which I copied from the maven package.

But nothing seems to be working.

Please help

Comment: Which jdk version are you using? Are you using the correct jdk in the java build path?

Comment: @SebastiánLópez its jdk 1.8

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DiliniU/frmv4ko8/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update March 2020* - this should be fixed in NetBeans 11.2 and later, released on 25th October 2019. Details in the [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-3251).

This is caused by a recent change in the JDK. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411279/java-with-maven-wouldnt-build-cannot-run-program-cmd-malformed-argument-has/58484737#58484737) for more information. Although the question relates to JDK11 the same change was made to JDK8 and the same solution (it is a work-around, really) applies.

Edit your `netbeans.conf` (you will find this in your netbeans directory under `etc`) to add `-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true` to the `netbeans_default_options` key. You can edit with notepad but you might need to do it as an Administrator depending on how you installed NB.

For example, mine looks like:

```
# JDK 11 made GTK 3 default on Linux. Unfortunately it makes
# NetBeans ugly on Linux with the default GTK+ Look and Feel,
# as a workaround -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 has been added to the 
# default command line arguments.
# (see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1344)
#
netbeans_default_options="-J-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true -J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false -J-Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes -J--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-modules=jdk.jshell -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J--add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"
```

Thanks to @Sephiroth for providing the answer.

Comment: Apparently I just copied paste yours and its working

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer I downgraded my java version from `jdk1.8.0_231` to `jdk1.8.0_221`.

Now everything is working fine.
Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This may be a workaround, but I guess the real issue lies somewhere else.

Comment: @jfmeier can you please give me some suggesions then?