# Cannot run program "cmd" java maven project in netbean 8.2 and jdk1.8.0_231

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

whenever i run my maven project it gives this error

```
Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\Users\Ertugrul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\imaging"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat" -Dexec.args="-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.imaging.Main" -Dexec.executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
```

please help me understanding this error and suggest me the possible solution for it.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411279/java-with-maven-wouldnt-build-cannot-run-program-cmd-malformed-argument-has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your netbeans is missing jdk or jdk is not linked with it. Make sure your jdk is installed and linked with it or Download netbeans with jdk from here.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html.