# The following error occurred while creating a maven project using idea

Tags: java

The error is as follows:

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3
```

I used all the ways which can find on Internet,such as change the localrepository or add other mirrors,but nothing is working, I was mad for the rest of the day because of this problem.

I hope someone can give me the answer to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522679/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5-or-one-of-its-dependencie

Comment: yes,but I can't download the plugin jar directly in a web browser,so I add the mirror of the aliyun of China,but it also doesn't work, so bad...

Comment: This issue can cause those errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764670/98811 . In a nut shell, the repos have switched to https only. Update your repository URLs to https://central.maven.org/maven2/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your maven configuration is missing the plugin repository definition.
Update your active profile by adding a pluginRepositories section as follows :

```
...
<Profile>
    ....
    <pluginRepositories>
       <pluginRepository>
           <id>Maven central</id>
           <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
           <layout>default</layout>
           <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    ....
</Profile>
```

You can always refer to the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for further readings