# Maven: Failed to retrieve pluginorg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

Below is my error when I execute maven build

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.975 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-19T15:45:25+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 405 -> [Help 1]
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer fil
    : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom. Return code is: 405 , ReasonPhrase:Method Not Allowed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have already been asked. It's a proxy/network issue.

[Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522679/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5-or-one-of-its-dependencie)

[Maven: Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819163/maven-failed-to-retrieve-plugin-descriptor-error)

[Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523039/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-install-plugin2-4-or-one-of-its-dependenc)

Please try Googling first, or making your question more specific, like mentioning what all steps you took already to solve the problem.

Comment: I tried adding up the proxies in settings.xml file, but still the error is thrown as I don't have a LAN proxy settings. Can you suggest me further steps to resolve this.

Comment: You will need to find the proxy details and enter them correctly in settings.xml. There isn't any alternative, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

Please add correct proxy information.

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>proxy</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.example.com</host>
    <port>8080</port>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

or apply it to your LAN settings. Whatever your requirment.
It is Proxy issue.