# Attempting to build Netbeans project using Maven

Tags: maven, netbeans, vaadin, glassfish-4

I'm currently working on deploying a Vaadin web application project to a GlassFish 4 server using Netbeans. On my local computer (running Windows 10), I can successfully deploy the file by simply using asadmin deploy (inside glassfish/bin) on the war file associated with the project. I can also just run the project inside NetBeans.

I then proceeded to scp over the project files to an Ubuntu (v. 16.04.4) environment, and also the GlassFish files. However, when I attempted the same technique this time, and then accessed the address of the Ubuntu environment via a browser in my local computer (since my project is scheduled to run on localhost, so in this case, the local host there would be a remote domain on my local computer), there was an HTTP error (resource not found).

My first hunch (and only one due to certain following circumstances) was that I needed to rebuild the war file inside the Ubuntu environment; naturally, since I had originally build the war file by building the NetBeans project, I thought I would do the same again. I then followed the instructions here:

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-commandline.html

Unfortunately during Step 5 of the very first section (Creating the NetBeans Platform Application), I ran into the following error log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/maven-install-plugin-2.5.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.5.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.7/maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.4.1/maven-assembly-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T08:25:02-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/609M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/lab/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

So, I searched online for this issue, and I found someone with a similar issue:

[Maven: Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819163/maven-failed-to-retrieve-plugin-descriptor-error)

I followed the responder's solution and added in a proxy to the settings.xml file. One discrepancy, however, is that my settings.xml file was inside usr/share/maven/conf instead of .m2 (which from what I've gathered from some online searching, doesn't exist in Ubuntu); to cover my bases, I thus created a .m2 folder in the Ubuntu environment and scp'ed over all the files in my (local) .m2 folder, and then copied the settings.xml file present in usr/share/maven/conf to .m2. Here's a screenshot of the edited part in the settings.xml file:

[image]

After changing that (it was originally commented, so I just had to uncomment and fill in a few things), I tried running the netbeans setup again. However, the output was almost identical, except sometimes there were a few extra references to the proxy I used at the end of the warning messages:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/maven-install-plugin-2.5.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.5.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.7/maven-antrun-plugin-1.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.4.1/maven-assembly-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): http://proxy.esl.cisco.com/
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): http://proxy.esl.cisco.com/
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): http://proxy.esl.cisco.com/
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): http://proxy.esl.cisco.com/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.358 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-06T09:41:15-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/609M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/lab/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

The second website I found where someone had a similar issue was this:

https://communities.bmc.com/thread/160101

However, in the responder's solution, I don't even know what SDK he's referring to, and a search of the entire file system in the Ubuntu environment revealed exactly 0 occurrences of archetype-catalog.xml (via find . -name "archetype-catalog")

So, any suggestions?

EDIT:
To clarify what my questions exactly are, they are the following:

1) Is my assumption correct that I can build a war locally and deploy it locally and have it work correctly, yet attempting to deploy the same war in a different address might result in erroneous behavior? More to the point, should I even worry about building the war in the Ubuntu environment? Because if not, I should probably start looking for other possible errors.

2) Why is maven not setting up Netbeans correctly EVEN AFTER adding the proxy to settings.xml?

3) Is there an Ubuntu-ized version of the solution that the person in the second website I visited (https://communities.bmc.com/thread/160101)? I.e., is there something similar to archetype-catalog that I can manipulate to solve the not-being-able-to-setup-Netbeans issue?

UPDATE:
So, I think I have the answer to the first question, though I'd still like the 2nd and 3rd questions answered so I'll still leave this post as unanswered. As for the first question, I think the answer is yes. I managed to get a workaround for all my woes of using netbeans to recompile the WAR via CLI inputs; instead, I set up a VNC connection for the Ubuntu environment and was then able to access it as a GUI. From there, I simply installed Netbeans, and rebuilt the project using the GUI version of Netbeans. This was not without struggles, but after I eventually got there, I tried accessing my project from my local (Windows environment), and it worked as expected.

Comment: Lots of details (which is good) but can you update your post to clarify the specific problem that need resolved? I've read your post twice and it's still not clear to me.

Comment: The issue looks like a network/firewall/proxy issue: `failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)`...

Comment: Hm @khmarbaise I see that message in the original error log but not after I added the proxy

Comment: Looks like your proxy is blocking the connection, that's why is failing.
The error calls `Http://proxy.esl.cisco.com/` . 
Have you configured proxy into Netbeans (look here http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/NetBeansSetup/netbeansSetup.html )? Or you could also configure it through Maven https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: @Leviand I've already configured proxy settings into Maven; I'll update the main post with a screenshot of that, so tell me if you see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've found the answer to my problems; looking down at other solutions on the Stack Overflow responses, I found that one person stated that the http proxy must be before the https proxy; I originally didn't even have the https proxy there (just the http), but I thought why not give it a shot anyways, and after adding the https proxy, the "failed to retrieve plugin descriptor warnings disappeared.

Comment: Can you please explain, in which file did you change from http to https?  Thanks in advance.