# VirtualBox: Ubuntu: Maven org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, maven-3

I have this error core when I try to maven install

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

I have found several related topics about this issue:

[Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522679/plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-clean-plugin2-5-or-one-of-its-dependencie)

[Maven: Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819163/maven-failed-to-retrieve-plugin-descriptor-error)

I know it is because of a LAN proxy configuration, the thing is, I don't have a LAN proxy, I'm pretty sure it is because of virtualbox network configuration, but I don't know how they can be related and more important how to solve it. Can somebody help me figure out how to solve this.

- Host: MAC OS X
- Virtualbox: 5.2.16
- Ubuntu: 18.04
- Maven: 3.5.2

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the error I run maven with -e swith and I noticed an SSL error, it was because I was using Java 1.7 and it doesn't support TLS 1.2 so I switched my `JAVA_HOME` to the 1.8 folder and it worked just fine.

If you have this same issue you can check your `JAVA_HOME` with this command in the terminal `echo $JAVA_HOME` if you need to change the path you can do it with `sudo nano /etc/environment`and change `JAVA_HOME` path. In my case the path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

Hope this helps, regards!